# Performance Testing for Classic ASP pages?

Tags: performance, asp-classic

I would like to know how to do performance testing for the old asp pages. Any tools out there that you've used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing special as to how stress test an ASP web application. Profiling is a different matter.

For stress testing I recommend [The Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/) (once and again and again :-) )

I haven't profiled ASP applications so I cannot help you there.

Comment: Also WCAT by Microsoft is useful http://www.iis.net/community/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=1466. Also -how would you use a _Java_ load tester on ASP??

Comment: You should run a load testing application in a different machine from the actual webserver, so I don't see any problem running a Java app testing an ASP (or whatever platform) application.

Comment: OK I guess I'll take a better look at it. I was just confused with the line "Load test anything that has a Java API".

Comment: @MikeMurko: That line refers to the programmability/extensibility of the tester (if it has a Java API, you can easily extend The Grinder to load test it). But it comes with ready made testers for common protocols.

Answer (score 6):

PS: I'm assuming by old ASP you are referring to "Classic ASP" not ASP.NET.

Here's a little piece of VBScript code I would put on pages to figure out how long they took to execute, you might find it useful.

```
<%
' Start the timer
starttime = timer()
%>

<!-- HTML and Code Here -->

<%
' End the timer
endtime = timer()
' Get the difference
benchmark = endtime - starttime
' Output the timing result
%>
<div class="noprint"><div class="debug">
<span class="text">Execute: <%= benchmark %> secs</span>
</div></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Way late to the question, but worth dropping in for the next poor soul who stumbles across this:

If you are looking to profile a particular ASP page, http://aspprofiler.sourceforge.net/ is absolutly awesome. I'd used it several years ago, forgotten I had it, and re-discovered it recently when trouble-shooting a page that took freakn'forever to load.

From their page:

> ASP Profiler is a line-level
>   performance profiler for Active Server
>   Pages (with VBScript) code. It shows
>   how your ASP page runs, which lines
>   are executed how many times, and how
>   many milliseconds each take.
>   Especially for heavy data-driven
>   pages, you can see exactly which lines
>   slow down the page, and optimize where
>   necessary.
>
> This program is itself written purely
>   in ASP and VBScript.

The only issue I had was that if a page recieved data from elsewhere, you can only input it via the QueryString.

Answer (score 1):

These threads may be useful:

- [Finding performance bottlenecks in a classic asp/sql server website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352597/finding-performance-bottlenecks-in-a-classic-aspsql-server-website#352884)
- [ASP.NET Stress Testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299518/aspnet-stress-testing#299784)
- [Profiling ASP.NET websites with EQATEC Profiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378617/profiling-aspnet-websites-with-eqatec-profiler#378730)

Like Vinko says, there's nothing "special" about testing ASP vs ASP.NET; any tool that can  test one can (usually) test the other.

Personally, I like using LoadRunner for testing and the MS Visual Studio Analyzer for profiling.

Answer (score 0):

[Apache Benchmark](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html), there is even Windows version. It tests number of request per second and average time